# How to Add and Remove Tab in AntDesign using Functional Component?

Tags: reactjs, antd

Hi I want to Add tabs and remove the tab using Functional Component:

Here what I tried.I saw the solution for this using classComponrnt but when I tried in functional Component Add is not working.

Please help me on this

Here is the code:

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { Tabs, Button } from 'antd';

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

const CreateTabs = () => {

    const initialPanes = [
        { title: 'Tab 1', content: 'Content of Tab 1', key: '1' },
        { title: 'Tab 2', content: 'Content of Tab 2', key: '2' },
    ]
     let newTabIndex = 0;

     const [activeState,setActiveState]=useState(initialPanes[0].key)
     const [panes,setPanes]=useState(initialPanes)
     
    const add = () => {

    let panes=[]
        const activeKey = `newTab${this.newTabIndex++}`;
        const newPanes = [...panes];
        newPanes.push({ title: 'New Tab', content: 'Content of new Tab', key: activeKey });
        setActiveState(activeKey );
        setPanes(newPanes)
      };

      
     const onChange = activeKey => {
        setActiveState(activeKey);
      };
     const onEdit = (targetKey, action) => {
        //[action](targetKey);
      };
    
    return (
        <div>
      <Tabs
          type="editable-card"
          onChange={onChange}
          activeKey={activeState}
          onEdit={onEdit}
        >
          {panes.map(pane => (
            <TabPane tab={pane.title} key={pane.key}>
              {pane.content}
            </TabPane>
          ))}
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    )
}

export default CreateTabs
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the add logic like below,

```
   const add = () => {
    const activeKey =
      (panes && panes.length ? +panes[panes.length - 1].key : 0) + 1;
    setActiveState(activeKey);
    setPanes((prev) => [
      ...prev,
      {
        title: "Tab " + activeKey,
        content: "Content of new Tab",
        key: activeKey
      }
    ]);
  };
```

remove:-

```
const remove = (key) => {
    setPanes((prev) => {
      const idx = prev.findIndex((item) => +item.key === +key);
      prev.splice(idx, 1);
      return [...prev];
    });
  };
```

Codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-meadow-049m7?file=/src/App.js:895-900

Comment: Logic for activeKey is flawed. If user creates pane with key 3. Then removes pane 2. Then creates a new pane it will also have activeKey 3 and generates unpredictable behaviour.

Comment: i will revisit the logic

Comment: Thank you, Can't we do custom add button here Instead of +?, Onclick of button I want to show pop up And select content for new tab

Comment: @SarunUK for Tabs design, assume there is a scenario where we are selecting multiple items and searching them. Based on items searched, it will load those many number of tabs. Problem is how to persist it. As soon as we search more, previous tabs are gone.