# How to render tabs dynamically using map in Ant design React

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant-Design tab , But I want it dynamically so I've used map function but the problem I'm facing is when I click on 2nd tab 2nd tab content is not displaying because When I checked All tabs in active state by default how to resolve this.

Here is the code:

```
 <Tabs tabPosition={"left"}>
                      {[1,2,3].map((item, index) => {
                          return(
                            <TabPane tab={`Tab ${item}`} key="1">
                            Content of Tab 1
                          </TabPane>
                        )})}
</Tab>
```

Can someone please suggest me the solution for this.

Comment: add a codesandbox please

Comment: I have answered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68066044/how-to-add-and-remove-tab-in-antdesign-using-functional-component/68066427#68066427). Is this the use case you are looking for ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Add and Remove Tab in AntDesign using Functional Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68066044/how-to-add-and-remove-tab-in-antdesign-using-functional-component)